# Clear introductory sources on Egyptian group-writing

Tags: resource-request, egyptian

I have come across the term *group-writing* (originally in a comment on [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38045/is-there-a-collection-of-ancient-egyptian-hieroglyphic-transliterations-of-forei/38049) but also elsewhere), apparently referring to a system the Egyptians used for transliterating foreign names. However, searching online has been surprisingly unhelpful in terms of finding reference material to understand what group-writing actually is; I guess because of a combination of obscurity and changing terminology.

I am looking for sources, preferably available freely online (I have JSTOR access but it is somewhat limited, and I'm not a member of an academic libraries), to understand what group-writing is. I'm a beginner when it comes to Egyptian but I'm comfortable reading technical material and just letting the extraneous detail wash over me.

Answer (score 2):

The best introduction I've found is Hoch's [*Semitic Words in Egyptian Texts of the New Kingdom and Third Intermediate Period*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7zvtpq), specifically chapter 6, *The Development of Group Writing*. This chapter mainly covers Middle Kingdom group writing, where Egyptian ꜣ was used for Semitic *r* or *l*, but also describes how it developed into the much less systematic New Kingdom group writing where ꜣ was used for *a* (which is elaborated on elsewhere in the book).

For a short summary: in the Old and Middle Kingdom, "group writing" developed to transcribe foreign words and names. This mostly consisted of uniliteral signs for consonants followed by ỉ or y (for an *i* vowel) or w (for an *u* vowel); *a* vowels were generally left unmarked. In the New Kingdom, this developed into a much larger and less formalized system where groups of two or more signs represented syllables, including all vowels, using ꜣ for *a*.

Comment: I know I already mentioned this on Reddit, but it seemed worth mentioning here too, for anyone else who finds the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently pointed to [Kilani's 2019 *Vocalisation in Group Writing: A New Proposal*](https://www.academia.edu/41989213/Kilani_Vocalisation_in_Group_Writing), which is significantly more modern than Hoch and focuses on the principles underlying group-writing rather than the representations of individual Semitic words. It's also, conveniently, available to read for free.

Unlike Hoch, Kilani proposes that three types of "groups" were distinguished: "consonant next to a back vowel", "consonant not next to a back vowel", and "continuant that's part of a complex onset". This only allows two types of vowels to be distinguished (back and non-back), giving transcriptions like *sArpUt* for `/sərp'ot/` "lotus". They also disagree on the interpretation of the sign Z4 (the dual strokes); Hoch claims this sign represents an `/i/` vowel, while Kilani claims it's more like a diacritic, modifying the function of a neighboring group (for example, turning *rA* into *r∅*, or *dA/d∅* into *dU*).